# Excel,CSV,PDF and Copy is not working in Datatable Tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, tabletools

i downloaded DataTables-1.9.4 and trying to run it, but Excel,CSV,PDF and Copy is not working only print option is working,I followed all steps given in document. please share the code which running with all files saving.

Comment: Please give us more detail..

Comment: downloaded the zip file from the link http://datatables.net/download/

Comment: and opened extras->TableTools and trying index lunch in chrome

Comment: I guess it should work without any changes.

Comment: but pdf,csv,excel and copy functionality is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run this in localhost,For me also this problem occurred, I tried to run it in Apache 2.2  in that also no use. then I applied it with Django+Apache2.2 it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike print button table tools works on Flash.

Make sure you have flash player installed.

Also the file copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf is present in your project folders and mentioned in right path like the example at http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/

Check in console whether you have any errors.

Comment: I didn't installed any flash player,Please share flash player download link and settings if any.

Comment: http://get2.adobe.com/flashplayer/

U can get flash player for your OS and browser here.

No settings. Just install and restart browser.

Comment: I saw in one of your comments that you are using chrome browser. It has inbuilt flash. So you dont have to install anything. Check the browser console in developer tools (F-12) for errors.

Comment: I have checked the console errors but there is no error and with example link http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/ pdf,csv,excel and copy functionality are working

Comment: please help me any one all features of DataTables-1.9.4 are working fine except this pdf,excel,CSV and copy.

Comment: can you create a js fiddle?

Comment: How to create it, i am new to development

Comment: U may have missed any of these resources
jquery.js,jquery.dataTables.js,ZeroClipboard.js,TableTools.js,TableTools.css

Include all these css or js in your code and see if it still doesnt work

Comment: here is the working code http://jsfiddle.net/mngxG/. Note that there are 5 external resources and jquery library included.

Comment: All Are there in my folder

Comment: Ok. Please go through the fiddle and tell me if any issues are there.

Comment: can you please download the Zip file from the link datatables.net/download and test it once

Comment: Yes that too works. But a quick thing though are you by any chance running it as html files ? I mean browser url will be like file:///<someting something>.html ?? If so run as localhost/folder/filename.html like that.

Comment: i tried that but getting error page like Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost

Comment: Please help it is important and urgent to me now

Comment: If you are new to development try learning some things first about webserver,webapplication etc. How to run a website in local. If you are working at some place try and get help from others there about them otherwise do search on google and find out :). Your code would work if you run with localhost I guess. if localhost/ give the error like you said. Its most probably that your system is not configured with a web server.